# Magento 2 Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Consumer\Config\Data

Tags: magento2, rabbit-mq

I've gone through the Megento Message queue process. I learned and tried one sample module in my local. but while run the queue:consumers:list command I am facing the following error.

**In AbstractFactory.php line 131:
Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Consumer\Config\Data**

For your further reference here I've added all my consumer related XML files. I hope this information are sufficient to identify the bug from your end. if you need any other info let me know it.

**communication.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Communication/etc/communication.xsd">
    <topic name="product_import_topic" request="string"/>
</config>
```

**queue_publisher:**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/publisher.xsd">
    <publisher topic="product_import_topic">
        <connection name="amqp" exchange="product_import_exchange" />
    </publisher>
</config>
```

**queue_topology:**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/topology.xsd">
    <exchange name="product_import_exchange" type="topic" connection="amqp">
        <binding id="productImportBiding" topic="product_import_topic" destinationType="queue" destination="product_import_queue"/>
    </exchange>
</config>
```

**queue_consumer.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/consumer.xsd">
    <consumer name="productImportConsumer" queue="product_import_queue" connection="amqp" handler="Practise\MesssageQueue\Model\Consumer\ImportProductConsumer::productImportProcess"/>
</config>
```

Thanks in advance for your better support.

Comment: This is probably too late, but I experienced a similar issue in the Firebear ImportExport module and tracked it down to a missing type in the docblock: Firebear\ImportExport\Model\QueueMessage\Image\ImportQueue. As paj answered, it's probably something in your consumer code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any obvious problems with the configuration you posted. Perhaps the problem lies with your consumer code.

I created a message queue test module which might help you test/debug your message queue module and configuration.

https://github.com/gaiterjones/Magento2_Gaiterjones_Rabbitmq